# How to search a file with adb.exe?

Tags: android, adb

Unix/Linux contains "find" command for searching files, but I do not know which command in android can be used to search for a file. Please give me an example.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As `find`and `grep` are not installed on devices I use, I am using the following:

```
adb shell ls -R / >tree.txt
```

After that I'm able to search in the file tree.txt on my pc using whatever software I like (for example notepad++ or grep).

Answer (score 49):

You may not find `find` and `grep` on all devices, so probably your safe bet is

```
   $ adb shell ls -lR | grep filename_you_want
```

on Linux/OSX, or

```
   > adb shell ls -lR | find "filename_you_want"
```

on Windows.

Comment: The distinction here being that the development machine's grep is being used - which should be fine on Linux or osx, windows devs may need to get a grep from mingw or whatever.

Comment: I noticed that `ls` on my device doesn't recognize `-lR`. Instead I have to give the options separately: `adb shell ls -l -R`

Comment: The option `-l`leeds to false positive matches, if you don't want to search access-rights, user, group and timestamp as well.

Comment: These commands will list a file, but not tell you where they are, which is why you want to use Find in the first place.

Comment: I used `adb shell "ls -lR [ top-level-dir ]/[ varying number of */ ]/[ known part of filename ]>` to find a glob pattern that matches the file, then started putting subdirs in the pattern - if the glob doesn't match, try the next subdir. It looked something like this: `/lib/libSmth*.so`, `/lib/*/libSmth*.so`, `/lib/*/*/libSmth*.so`, `/lib/X11/*/libSmth*.so`, `/lib/xv/*/libSmth*.so`, `/lib/xv/subdir1/libSmth*.so`, `/lib/xv/subdir2/libSmth*.so` and so on. Pretty tedious, but with enough patience it can be a crude substitute for `find`.

Comment: Even better, skip the `-lR` and it will give you the path itself: `adb shell "ls system/*/*/libDivxDrm.so"` -> `system/vendor/lib/libDivxDrm.so`

Comment: But it only show if file exist or not, not the full path, example: -r--r----- root     log             0 2016-05-10 02:00 vmallocinfo

Comment: In order to figure out the whole path you can do something like:
`adb shell ls -lR | grep filename_you_want -B 30` which will show you the thirty lines previous to the match. Unless its parent folder has many children, the path to the directory should be displayed.

Answer (score 7):

`find` doesn't work for me on my device. Doesn't seem to be installed!

However this sort of works for me:

```
adb shell
```

(then in shell)

```
ls -laR | grep filename_you_want
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `grep` was only added to stock android builds sometime in the 4.x series, though busybox ports common in custom roms have had it for a long time.

Comment: This shows the files I'm looking for but no path information.  How do I include the path?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I think for that you need `find`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tiny script that should work in zsh and bash.  It simulates what you might see if you could run `find /` on your Android device:

```
adb shell ls -R / |
    while read line
    do
            line=$(echo $line | tr -d '\r')

            if [[ "$line" =~ ^/.*:$ ]]
            then
                    dir=${line%:}

            elif [[ "$line" = "opendir failed, Permission denied" ]]
            then
                    echo "find: $dir: Permission denied"

            else
                if [[ "$dir" = "/" ]]; then dir=""; fi

                echo "$dir/$line"
            fi
    done
```

Because it lists all the immediate child directories before descending into them, the output is a little out of order (for example `/system` is listed right away but `/system/media` doesn't show up until much later).  Depending on your needs, you could slap `| sort -u` at the end of the script, but it should be all right for all your basic `grep`ing needs.

Answer (score 3):

Some android devices don't include `find` or `grep` in `$PATH`. However they might include `busybox`. (In my experience, most of them can use `busybox`). So you might use them as follow:

> adb shell

and then

> busybox find . "file.txt"

or something like that

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me because they either didn't provide the path to the file I was looking for or returned so many file names that it wasn't useful.

For me the following worked using `busybox`:

`adb shell busybox find / -name <your_file_name.here> 2>/dev/null`

The `/` tells the `find` command to search from the root directory. But you could use `.` instead to search from current directory. Like this:

`adb shell busybox find . -name <your_file_name.here> 2>/dev/null`

The `2>/dev/null` quiets permission denied responses, otherwise I get a lot of them and it clogs the screen.