# How do you manually remove an installed library from an Android device

Tags: android

I have been developing an Android application in which the name of a native library has changed. The original library (we will call liba.so) has compiled JNI code in it that has been changed in the new library (we will call libb.so). However, when I push the application that is now using libb.so, the device with liba.so on it is still executing some code in liba.so and not the respective code in libb.so. However, a second device that never has liba.so on it is properly executing the code in libb.so. I have confirmed that liba.so is no where in the Java files, and is not even being compiled anymore. So, how do I remove liba.so from the first device?

**UPDATE**: In case it matters, the device is NOT rooted.

Comment: Hook it up in debug mode and search the filesystem?

Comment: Do you mean via adb shell? If so, do you know which command? I have tried "find", but it reports that that command is not found.

Comment: Can't you parse the entire file system if the device is connected as a media device?  This would also mean you don't need debug mode.

Comment: Sort of. My device is not rooted, so what you can see in places is controlled. I tried finding the file using the method suggested in another SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148353/how-to-search-a-file-with-adb-exe), but the file wasn't found, I think because I am not rooted.

Comment: you tried them all? because there are ways in that post describing how to do it with find on a win machine (assuming you have mingw installed) as well as busybox was recommended also.

Comment: Yes I have (for all of the linux equivalents -- I do not have Windows). I also looked into BusyBox, but the applications says it can only be installed on a rooted device, which I cannot do.

Comment: Sorry, I have no more to add. Good luck