# Subsitute of "locate" command in adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

I wanted to find a particular file in my android device. In Linux, we have `locate` command to search for a file if its name is known. But while i was running the same command in adb shell, it gave this error:

```
locate: not found
```

So, is there any way to install locate in android or any other substitute of this command?

Comment: I don't think using `locate` is no different from creating the database like `find / 2>/dev/null > your_database` and searching it `grep keyword your_database`.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148353/how-to-search-a-file-with-adb-exe

Comment: install `busybox` and try `busybox locate`

Comment: I looked for two versions of busybox and found no locate command in busybox. @Rilwan